# angular 5 ngx-carousel with centered active item

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel

im trying to make custom carousel, showing 3 items with clickable item in the middle.
[something like this lul!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev0Bt.png)

im using the ngx-carousel in my angular 5 project, ive made the carousel showing 3 items, but im confuse to make the middle get bigger and clickable with some event.

here's my html code :

```
<ngx-carousel [inputs]="carouselTileOne" (carouselLoad)="carouselTileOneLoad()">
<ngx-tile NgxCarouselItem >
    <div class="wBg">
        <div class="tile" [style.background]="'url(' + tile + ')'">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../../assets/images/img-product (3).png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</ngx-tile>
<ngx-tile NgxCarouselItem>
    <div class="wBg">
        <div class="tile" [style.background]="'url(' + tile + ')'">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../../assets/images/img-product (3).png" alt="">
        </div>    
    </div>
</ngx-tile>
<ngx-tile NgxCarouselItem>
    <div class="wBg">
        <div class="tile" [style.background]="'url(' + tile + ')'">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../../assets/images/img-product (3).png" alt="">
        </div>      
    </div>
</ngx-tile>
<ngx-tile NgxCarouselItem>
    <div class="wBg">
        <div class="tile" [style.background]="'url(' + tile + ')'">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../../assets/images/img-product (3).png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</ngx-tile>
<i NgxCarouselPrev class="leftRs fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i NgxCarouselNext class="rightRs fa fa-chevron-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and for the component.ts im using the file from the demo here [ngx-carousel demo component.ts](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngx-carousel/blob/master/demo/src/app/app.component.ts)

any sugestion what should i do ? or give me another refrence.